# Call to undefined function settings_fields()

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am a newbie to Wordpress plugin creation. I am creating a custom plugin and for this, I have to make wp_admin custom settings API.

When I call a setting field by `settings_field('setting_group')`. I received an error call to undefined function settings_field.

Any help will be appreciated

```
<h1> Pagination Settings </h1>
<h2>Define Number of Button</h2>
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php settings_fields( 'wp-settings-group' ); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php

   settings_fields("wp-settings-group");
   do_settings_sections("your_slug"); //The slug name of the page

?>
<input name="cust_options[submit]" id="submit_options_form" type="submit"  value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Settings','text-domain'); ?>" />
```

you need to do this to Prints out all settings sections.